# How to use jQuery.map() on array of objects to return array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to convert an array of objects to array of arrays using map.

For example if I have this:

```
var ObjArr = [{ a:1,b:2 },{ a:2,b:3 },{ a:3,b:4 }];
var ArrArr = $.map(ObjArr, function(n,i){
   return [ n.a, n.b ];
});
```

So that the result would be:

```
ArrArr = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

With the [`jQuery.map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and [`map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) methods  you need to double wrap the return value:

```
var ArrArr = $.map(ObjArr, function(n,i){
   return [[ n.a, n.b ]];
});
```

...otherwise for some reason it concats the Array being returned. This way it concats the outer Array, and placing the content (the inner Array) at the next index.

Comment: It works! However, could you tell me is there any reason why jQuery does it?

Comment: *could you tell me is there any reason why jQuery does it*: Probably to make `.map()` not restricted to a 1:1 mapping.  e.g. Returning `[]` can filter out the element without using a separate `.filter()`.  Likewise `.map()` can also be used to flatten a list of lists.