# Autocomplete: Why will my response object not return both first and last name ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm totally new to JQuery Autocomplete using Ajax. I have got 90% the way there with the code below. Using the Chrome dev tools I can see **all** my values coming through next to the `firstname:item.firstname1`, that is to say, firstname,lastname, telephone etc. And if I have 3 matches they all are displayed sequentially. Then I screw things up. The `lastname` and the  `telephone` objects appear to be redundant and nothing appears next to them. Furthermore none of the values appear as options on the screen. However, three **empty** options show up for the 3 objects which were found. My `select:function(event, ui)` does not work either. I have read the docs 100 times I am not getting anywhere fast.

I'd be very grateful if you could help to get it to work, but also to **explain** what I have done wrong. TKS !

Javascript:

```
 $('#customer').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response,term) {
        var param = request.term;
        $.ajax({
            url: "quotes/customer_search/"+param,
            dataType: "json",
            type:"GET",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        firstname:item.firstname1,  // My objects appear here. 
                        lastname:item.lastname1, // these are redundant
                        telephone:item.telephone1, // redundant
                    };
                }));//END Success
            },
        });//END AJAX
    },

    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
        "Selected: " + ui.item.firstname + " " + ui.item.lastname :
        "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );


    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="customer">Birds: </label>
    <input id="customer" class="ui-autocomplete-input" >
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
    Result:
    <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which helped me solve my problem:

[How to use JQuery Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875649/how-to-use-jquery-map-on-array-of-objects-to-return-array-of-arrays)

Once I had looked at that I had realized that my syntax for my reponse object needed changing to the code below. Once changed everything worked.

```
success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item,customer) {

                    return  [item.firstname1+' '+item.lastname1+' '+item.telephone1]

                }));//END Success
            },
```