# json to key value array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some json data, that looks like :

```
[{
"key": "Jan",
  "value": "400"
}, {
  "key": "Apr",
  "value": "500"
}, {
  "key": "Aug",
  "value": "24058.635"
}, {
  "key": "Sep",
  "value": "2160"
}, {
  "key": "Nov",
  "value": "115425"
}, {
  "key": "Dec",
  "value": "32570"
}]
```

I need to convert this to a key value pair array that should be like

```
[
  [Jan, 400],
  [Apr, 500],
  [Aug, 24058.635],
  [Sep, 2160],
  [Nov, 115425],
  [Dec, 32570]
]
```

Somebody please help me with Jquery or Javascript code to do this conversion.

Comment: Basically an exact duplicate of [How to use jQuery.map() on array of objects to return array of arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4875649/218196), but jQuery is weird.

Comment: You should definitely read [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: @AJIN did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` function to iterate on them and return an array you want.

```js
let json =  [{"key":"Jan","value":"400"},{"key":"Apr","value":"500"},{"key":"Aug","value":"24058.635"},{"key":"Sep","value":"2160"},{"key":"Nov","value":"115425"},{"key":"Dec","value":"32570"}];

let obj = json.map(item => [item['key'], item['value']]);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: console is showing **json.map is not a function(…)**

Comment: @AJIN, What look does your json obj has? In my case it is an array. If you have it like a string, then do `let json = JSON.parse(yourString)` and after that use map function

Comment: I am processing the response from an ajax method.

Comment: after parsing output is showing like **[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]**

Comment: Create a fiddle and show your code.Or for first make sure you get the `json` object as mine

Comment: its working in fiddle..but the output is not showing in correct format. All keys and values get mixed up.

Comment: It is the `alert` function output. Actually the `obj` contains the expected result

Answer (score 1):

with **forEach** method .

```js
var a= [{"key":"Jan","value":"400"},{"key":"Apr","value":"500"},{"key":"Aug","value":"24058.635"},{"key":"Sep","value":"2160"},{"key":"Nov","value":"115425"},{"key":"Dec","value":"32570"}];
var ans=[];
a.forEach(function(a){
ans.push([a["key"],a["value"]]);
})
console.log(ans);
```

with **map** method .

```js
var a= [{"key":"Jan","value":"400"},{"key":"Apr","value":"500"},{"key":"Aug","value":"24058.635"},{"key":"Sep","value":"2160"},{"key":"Nov","value":"115425"},{"key":"Dec","value":"32570"}];

var ans=a.map(function(a){
return [a["key"],a["value"]];
})
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: both methods are showing output as : **[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]**

Comment: @AJIN  `JSON.stringify(output)` only to show output as string . but keep output as it it . output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```js
var input = [{
  "key": "Jan",
  "value": "400"
}, {
  "key": "Apr",
  "value": "500"
}, {
  "key": "Aug",
  "value": "24058.635"
}, {
  "key": "Sep",
  "value": "2160"
}, {
  "key": "Nov",
  "value": "115425"
}, {
  "key": "Dec",
  "value": "32570"
}];

var output = input.map(function(obj) {
  return [obj.key, obj.value]
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: output is showing as **[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]**

Comment: if you would like to display it, you could use JSON.stringify(output).

Comment: If you need to access, you should use output[someIndex][0] for Key and output[someIndex][1] for Value

Comment: i am not accessing the data at any index. I am passing this output on to a function where a graph will be generated with this data.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Array [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method :**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
"key": "Jan",
  "value": "400"
}, {
  "key": "Apr",
  "value": "500"
}, {
  "key": "Aug",
  "value": "24058.635"
}, {
  "key": "Sep",
  "value": "2160"
}, {
  "key": "Nov",
  "value": "115425"
}, {
  "key": "Dec",
  "value": "32570"
}];

var newArr = jsonObj.map(function(item) {
  return [item['key'],item['value']];
});

console.log(newArr);
```

**Using JavaScript [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop :**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
"key": "Jan",
  "value": "400"
}, {
  "key": "Apr",
  "value": "500"
}, {
  "key": "Aug",
  "value": "24058.635"
}, {
  "key": "Sep",
  "value": "2160"
}, {
  "key": "Nov",
  "value": "115425"
}, {
  "key": "Dec",
  "value": "32570"
}];

var newArr = [];
for (var i in jsonObj) {
  newArr.push([jsonObj[i].key,jsonObj[i].value]);
}

console.log(newArr);
```