# Retrieve key from form with JavaScript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to retrieve form results into an array. This displays a number of checkboxes to the user based off of input from the $result_columns_c array.

```
foreach($result_columns_c as $key=>$value){
echo "<td width='20%'><input type='checkbox' class='input_options_sqlUpdate_a' 
name='input_options_sqlUpdate_a[$value]' value='$value'> $key</td>";
}

<script>
function optionsSubmit(){
    var inputs = $('.input_options_sqlUpdate_a:checked');
    input_a  = [].map.call(inputs, function( input ) {
        return input.value;
    })
    $.get("../index.php", {input_sqlQuery_a:input_a, sqlQuery:'true', sqlUpdate:'true', serialize:'true'}, function(data){
        $("#test").html(data);
    });
}       
</script>
```

However, this only creates an array with the values. How can I create an array with the key($value1) as well, or preferably, just retrieve the results from the form as an associative array?

Comment: Try [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: `return {[input.name]:input.value}`

Comment: @ guest271314 Is there an easy way to just get the value([$value1]), instead of getting the entire name (input_options_sqlUpdate_a[$value1])?

Comment: @charlietfl serializearray() could work, but how do I get it to work with $('.input_options_sqlUpdate_a:checked')? That does not return an array? Is there an easy way to get input, from checked values, as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can object destructuring at `Array.from()` or `.map()` call, computed property to return an object reflecting `.name` and `.value` of `input` as key, value pairs. You can use `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/^.+\[|\]/g` to match beginning of `.name` property to and including `[` character or `]` character, with replacement set to empty string `""`.

```js
var inputs = $("input");

var input_a  = Array.from(inputs, function({name, value}) {
                 return Array(name.replace(/^.+\[|\]/g, ""), value);
               });
               
console.log(input_a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='input_options_sqlUpdate_a' 
name='input_options_sqlUpdate_a[$value1]' value='$value2'>
<input type='checkbox' class='input_options_sqlUpdate_a' 
name='input_options_sqlUpdate_a[$value3]' value='$value4'>
```

Comment: This works. However, it brings back the entire name(input_options_sqlUpdate_a[$value1]), instead of just the value([$value1]). Is there a simple way to just get the value?

Comment: This brings back each [$value1] as an array. I need to be able to concatenate the different arrays automatically. I think I can figure out a way to do it from here, but it would be awesome if you could tell me.

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate the different arrays automatically"?

Comment: [$value1] is a different value for each checkbox. My example only has 1, but the script has many. Your solution brings back a different array for each checkbox. I need to get them all in the same array, with the different values in [$value1] as the key, before I call the PHP script with JQuery.

Comment: @ArthurWalker Can you include `html` that you are describing at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The edited Question does not contain the rendered `html` the you described. What is resulting `html`, and what is expected resulting array or array of objects?

Comment: I misunderstood. Say that the loop iterates twice and the values for [$value1] are 1 and 2 respectively, There would be two different arrays and they would look like this; 1=>$value2, 2=>$value2. There is a different array for each [$value1].

Comment: @ArthurWalker An array of arrays `[[0, "$value1"], [1, "$value2"]]` from two `<input>` elements? Or an array of objects where key is index of array `[{0:"$value1"}, {1:"$value2"}]`? Original Question does not appear to mention index, but rather get value surrounded by `[`, `]` within `.name` attribute, yes?

Comment: Yes; Array ( [0] => Array ( [last_name] => last_name ) [1] => Array ( [company_id] => company_id ) [2] => Array ( [position] => position ) . The format is right. I just need everything to be a singular array without PHP being used.

Comment: `$.map()` concatenates returned array elements to existing array. You can use `Array.from()` or your orignal approach of `[].map.call()` See updated post

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875649/how-to-use-jquery-map-on-array-of-objects-to-return-array-of-arrays

Comment: Not gathering what you mean.